# What role does the sampling fraction play in the simple random sample variance formula?

Tags: variance, sampling, finite-population

Consider a survey where the population being estimated is finite.  Using a simple random sample, you draw $n<N$ data.  The sampling fraction is $f=\frac{n}{N}$.  The variance will be $(1-f)\frac{s^2}{n}$.  Can someone explain how the sampling fraction effects this formula?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Is it about the finite population correction?

Comment: @gung Yes! How does it affect the variance of a simple random sample?

Comment: @gung Do you understand my question?

Comment: Did I get it wrong? If so, please edit to correct it. Just make sure it is clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

In many cases, $f$ is neglected when evaluating the sampling variance. Think about it : if you sample $n = 10 000~$ units among $~N = 300 000 000~$, then $~ f \approx 3 \cdot 10^{-6} \ll 1$.

The most important terms of this formula are : $n$, the sample size, and $s^2$, the variance of the variable you're trying to measure.

Nevertheless, it is somehow logical to see $f$ appear in the formula. Indeed, if $f = 1$ (census), variance of the SRS has to be $0$.